# Angular 4: deleteRow in table, splice error

Tags: html, angular, typescript, splice

I have a quick question regarding Angular 4 and splicing.

Below is my Typescript code:

`delete(appIndex: number): void {
    this.apps.splice(appIndex, 1);
  }`

Below is my HTML Code:

```
<tr  *ngFor="let app of apps; let i = index">
      <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text1"  tabindex="1"> {{ text1 }}</td>
      <td><input type="text"  [(contenteditableModel)]="text2" tabindex="2">{{ text2 }}</td>
      <td><input type="text"  [(contenteditableModel)]="text2" tabindex="3">{{ text3 }}</td>
      <td class="actions">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" (click)="delete(i)">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

The issue I am running into is 'Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined. When I further researched into this, I found that in Angular 1, '$scope' was used in order to access within the DOM. How do I replicate this in Angular 4?

UPDATE:

I have edited my code to read like:

Typescript:

```
 delete(appIndex: number) {
this.apps.splice(appIndex, 1);
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

}

HTML:

```
  <tr class="odd">
      <td class="status"><img src="../../../assets/images/Red_Circle_1.png" class="redcircle"></td>
      <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text4"> {{ text4 }}</td>
      <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text5">{{ text5 }}</td>
      <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text6">{{ text6 }}</td>
      <td class="actions">
          <input type="button" value="Delete" *ngFor="let app of apps; let i = index" (click)="delete(i)">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is the  plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2KaXodEe2CbQdLXZtVaC?p=preview

I'm not getting any errors now, but the delete button is not displaying at all.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: that looks correct. there must be something else going on. `this.apps` in your component code is the same scope as `apps` in your html template. Is your apps property used anywhere else within your template?

Comment: I don't think it is. I will double check. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: No it is not...

Comment: What is the `contenteditableModel` attribute?

Comment: https://www.namekdev.net/2016/01/two-way-binding-to-contenteditable-element-in-angular-2/

Comment: Your data structure: `apps` is a `Array` or a `Object`.

Comment: apps: any[];
This is how I have apps defined.

Comment: The simplest way to get a solution would be to post a example on: http://plnkr.co/ . This way we know more and can do more.

Comment: Hope that helps!

Comment: Updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/2KaXodEe2CbQdLXZtVaC?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work without problem so long as you are executing `delete` from the component whose template you called it from.

Here is basically the same code working: [**Live demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9micc1?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thank you for the demo, it is very helpful. I actually had separate td's within my HTML instead of a string array in my Typescript file. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @MeenaMana I don't understand what you're asking, but play around with the demo to find out.

Comment: Ok sure. I will do that.

Comment: I implemented the code according to what you had suggested, however, now I am not seeing the button for Delete. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Will update the question.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2KaXodEe2CbQdLXZtVaC?p=preview 
Please see this link to view the Plunker.

Comment: @MeenaMana in your plunkr, your `index.html` is wrong. This file should not have the component template. Instead, it should have the root component selector `<my-app></my-app>` to tell Angular where to put the component. The component template should only be in `app.html`

Comment: how do I get my app.ts to recognize app.html as the template? I have tried setting templateUrl: 'src/app.html', but it still doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: @MeenaMana your app is not running at all because you have no script or script tag in `index.html`. Start over with a working demo and replace the code with your own. Or use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), which I find easier for Angular demos.